# How to Write mysql Select LIKE cause in php

Tags: php, mysql

How to write this mysql query,

```
SELECT * FROM  `content`WHERE  `language_option_tag` LIKE  "%English%"
```

into php code where I only select the data which user have been POST by FORM

```
$sql .= 'SELECT * FROM  `content` WHERE  `language_option_tag` LIKE "%' .$lang_name. '%" ;
```

Comment: what is the problem? query is correct/

Comment: yes query is work but I want to show the result which user has select from Form and send POST method to PHP, so I would replace "%English%" to "%' .$lang_name. '%" and it show all of data.

Comment: use this `$lang_name = $_POST['your_lang'];`.

Comment: yes,I already use and it work  $lang_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['lang_name'],ENT_QUOTES);

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Can you provide with more details

Comment: ok here I have 3 stage, page 1 is user click the field ,send this field to the PHP page with POST method,

`$("#sub-lang-eng").click(function() {
    
    $.post("../select-query.php",
    {
     lang_name:"English",
    },
    function(data,status){
    
      $("#results-handler").html(data);
     
    });
    return false;
    
    });
`

Then at _select-query.php_ page  , collect 
`$lang_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['lang_name'],ENT_QUOTES);`

Connect with Database,and show the result at first page.

Answer (score 1):

```
$lang_name = $_POST['your_lang'];    
$sql = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE `language_option_tag` LIKE '%$lang_name%'" ;
```

Comment: Be careful to ensure that `$lang_name` has been properly escaped; better to parameterise a prepared statement.

Comment: This is same as OP's query.

Answer (score 1):

```
$lang_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['selected_your_lang']);    
$sql = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE `language_option_tag` LIKE '%$lang_name%'";
```

**Note: Always use mysql_real_escape_string() when you are passing data from form..to stop SQL injection.**

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated and using it is not a good idea

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a bcaktick, maybe it's just a typo but this is causing an error and also the way you use like should be different, change as follow

```
$sql .= 'SELECT * FROM  `content` WHERE  `language_option_tag` LIKE '% .$lang_name. %' ; 
                        ^here is missing backtick `.                ^ here there was a mistake
```

Then I  would like to remember you that you are at risk of `sql injection`, have a look here [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). You should use prepared statment to avoid any risk

Comment: If one looks at [the source of the OP's original post](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2ad17242-d6ce-49e6-a384-7fa5ec815818/view-source), it's clear that the typo was simply markdown formatting; the "mistake" after `LIKE` is not a mistake - the SQL string literal must be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbconnection= mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "dbname");    
$lang = $_POST["lang"];
$lang = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnection, $lang); // To prevent SQL injection
$sql = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE `language_option_tag` LIKE '%$lang%'" ;
```

About usage of mysqli visit http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Better to parameterise a prepared statement.

Comment: It has show Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/mydomain/public_html/project/select-query.php on line 51

Comment: My bad, first parameter is DB connection variable, edited my answer